# How do I print an image some percentage smaller than it is?

Tags: windows, printing, images

How do I print an image some percentage smaller than it is?

For example I have an image of a protractor here https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlmEv.jpg

[image]

And as you can see, when I print it out, it comes out quite big.

Currently it is  529px by 399 px.

[image]

Mspaint has a "resize" button. If I click that and choose 50%

I get this

[image]

265x200

Then if I try to print it, I get

[image]

So, it comes out A)The same size  and B) Blurred(lost resolution!)

I just want to print out that round protractor, but some percentage smaller!

Comment: Why not use a better image editor, for example the free [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround with Paint is to click the **bottom right thumb** to resize the image then **select the image and move it to the center**

It works because the whole image area will be fit inside the page margins. Since the area is now larger, the image will appear smaller in the printed page

[image: Demo]

Comment: but can you explain what is actually happening.. Why it didnt resize? Why moving it to the centre has anything to do with it?!

Comment: @barlop explained. Increasing the image area size will decrease the size of the object in the page. The movement is just for placing it at the center of the page instead of at the corner so you can skip that if unnecesary

Comment: You write "Increasing the image area size will decrease the size of the object in the page" <--- You mean It will decrease the size of the object relative to the page.   And then as you say "The movement is just for placing it at the center of the page instead of at the corner so you can skip that if unnecesary "

Comment: Where you wrote  "resize the image then select the image and move it to the center" <---  I guess you mean resize the image then move the object. Or to put it differently, resize the (what one could call image space, which represents the paper), so the object takes a smaller percentage of the paper, then select the object and move it to the center.

Comment: I like this answer, but some of the terminology is a bit odd to me..I have heard the word "handle".. do dragging the bottom right corner. but  i've never heard it referred to as a "thumb"!  "bottom right thumb "

Answer (score 2):

You can go to *File > Print > Page setup* and increase the margin

[image: Page setup dialog]

Then check the result in *File > Print > Print preview*. For example a margin setting of all 20 mm for the above image results in

[image: 20 mm margins]

And when I change all the margins to 50 mm then the result looks like this

[image: 50 mm margins]

Answer (score 1):

I find MS Word more reliable while correcting small things before printing without losing quality.

Open MS Word, paste in the big picture.
Correct its borders if they went off the page

Correct the borders of the page according to the need:
[image]

Select the picture.

Format -> Position -> Choose the one you need (I usually choose the middle one).

[image]